# Get current wallpaper absolute path?

Tags: android, wallpaper

How do we get a current wallpaper `absolute path`

Comment: did u get only wallpaper path or image?

Comment: what is it that you want to achieve by getting the path?

Comment: My current wallpaper stored location as Internal Memory. How to identify that path.

Answer (score 10):

On Android 4.2 the wallpaper is located at:

```
/data/system/users/0/wallpaper
```

Replace the `0` with your user id (take a look in `/data/system/users`).

Comment: Is it accessible to apps without using root?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are looking in the phone's root directory to start, NOT on the SDcard. Once you get to the right subdirectory the wallpaper file will just be called "wallpaper" and until you copy it to the SDcard and rename it to "YourName.jpg" the picture viewers may not recognize it as an image file.

I tried both ES File Explorer and Root Explorer (download from Marketplace) to copy the file from the phone root area., i.e. phone `ROOT/data/data/com.android.settings/files/wallpaper..`.it's the lowest level of the phone storage itself, similar to "computer" in windows.

Probably the File Explorer on your phone won't let you access the root (your phone shouldn't need ROOT privileges just to copy the file)

Comment: I don't know if that's where the OS stores the wallpapers... At least on my Nexus 7 there's no directory lower than ROOT/data/ in that file path.

Comment: *To Padma Kumar:* Thank you! You right, I found current wallpaper here: **ROOT/data/data/com.android.settings/files/wallpaper**

Answer (score 1):

use `wallpaperManager` and call `getWallpaperInfo`. This will return you a `wallpaperinfo` object which contains all the info about the wallpaper. [Read more about the wallpapernfo here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperInfo.html)

I would imagine that the current wallpaper will be stored in a private system folder.

Comment: sorry, My Current Wallpaper is stored at internal sdcard / memory. How to identify that path.

Comment: AFAIK once you set a wallpaper from your own images android copies it to over to the `wallpaper` file. so even if you delete the file in your gallery that you used to set the wallpaper manually your wallpaper will stay. So again the question remains what is it that you want to achieve once you have the path to the wallpaper file? as there can be other ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: I have no idea. Can you give me any example for achieve the same result in other ways..

Comment: look mate how can I help you if I don't what is it that you want to achieve once you have the path? lets assume you can get the path what is it that you want to do next?

Comment: Sorry, When i open the my application automatically changed the current wallpaper. When i closed my application automatically applied to the previous wallpaper.

Comment: you mean that the background of your application looks different to the one on the home screen? if you want the phone wallpaper to be background of your application you need to use the `wallpaper service`.A wallpaper service is responsible for showing a live wallpaper behind applications that would like to sit on top of it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13516/discussion-between-user1474868-and-orlymee)

Answer (score 0):

On Android Oreo and using one of the provided wallpapers from the system, the wallpaper I wanted wasn't on the path mentioned by the accepted answer but I found the apk that had it on a system folder.

I got it from the path: system/framework/framework-res.apk
I had to open the apk and extract: /res/drawable-nodpi-v4/default_wallpaper.png.

Comment: I think the question is about general & not to any specific version of Android. And don't you think your defined way is more complex?

Comment: I added my answer because the accepted answer didn't work for me on Oreo. As a valid solution and a different alternative I don't see why the down vote.

Comment: the question is about "current wallpaper" and that can be any image that user has set as wallpaper, ... not necessarily the default one provided by the device...

Comment: Ok, I see your point now. I edited my answer to make it clear it's a specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Android Oreo is not in the place from other comments

Internal Storage/Android/data/com.android.systemui/files/backupwallpapers

I just had to find a wallpaper that I deleted from my downloads folder.

Comment: Thats correct, but in my case (Samsung Galaxy SM-A600FN with Oreo) the files are corrupt, not valid jpeg's.

Answer (score 0):

Download the apk file ...

go to this path...you can find it here

Download\com.amber.launcher.skin.samsung.galaxy_2018-08-24\res\drawable-nodpi-v4\bg_wallpaper.jpg